# Inheriting data from SQLAlchemy to another Python class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to make a Base class from which to inherit the engine and use the session and not always declare them in each model class
For example
I have this now

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import config


class Action:
    engine = create_engine(config.DATABASE_URL)

    base = declarative_base()

    Base = automap_base()
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

    Action = Base.classes.actions
    session = Session(engine)
```

But I wouldn't want to rewrite the connection to the engine every time, but just use the functions from the database immediately.
It should be mentioned that I want to connect sqlalchemy to an already existing database